# Как запустить готового чат менеджера на питоне 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста. Я только сделал вк бота , а запустить и потестить не могу(не знаю как)
Вот код:

```
import vk_api
import time
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="")

while True:
    messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unread"})
    if messages["count"] >= 1:
        id = messages["items"][0]["last_messages"]["from_id"]
        body = messages["items"][0]["last_messages"]["text"]
        if body.lower() == "привет":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет"})
        else:
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Я не понял тебя"})
    time.sleep(1)
```

Разъясните пожалуйста, как "пообщаться" с ботом .
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, вам необходимо создать сообщество вконтакте. В настройках необходимо получить токен этого самого сообщества (https://vk.com/dev.php?method=access_token здесь вы можете почитать об этом подробнее). И ввести его вот в эту строчку

```
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="ваш токен")
```

Затем можете смело запускать скрипт и общаться с вашим ботом)
P.S. Важное уточнение, бот сможет писать вам, только после того, как вы разрешите группе писать вам сообщения (это можно сделать в шапке). ЛИБО после того, как вы напишите в сообщения сообщества что-либо.

Comment: Автор как раз и спрашивает "как запустить". А токен у него есть, просто я удалил его из вопроса.

Comment: Ну в таком случае, не вижу проблемы. python script.py Теперь достаточно просто написать самому боту, и все заработает

Comment: А что значит запускать скрип. Разъясните пожалуста

Comment: Запустить готовый скрипт необходимо в командной строке/терминале командой python  "имя скрипта.ру". Если выходит ошибка, то необходимо все так же установить доп. модули, командой pip install "имя модуля". В вашем случае - pip install vk_api

Comment: Запустил, но ничего не выводит

Comment: теперь пишите боту

Comment: если скрипт работает - достаточно начать "общаться" с ботом